# Connectedness and evenly coveredness.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $p:E\rightarrow B$ be continuous and surjective.
Suppose that $U$ is an open set of $B$ that is evenly covered by $p$.Show that if $U$ is connected, then the partition of $p^{-1}(U)$ into slices is unique.

So I need to show that if $p^{-1}(U)=\bigcup_\alpha V_\alpha = \bigcup_\gamma W_\gamma$, where $\{ V_\alpha \} , \{ W_\gamma \}$ are disjoint open sets in $E$.

Now, I am not sure but since $U$ is connected and it's homeomorphic to $V_\alpha$ and $W_\gamma$, we have that $p^{-1}(U)=V_\alpha = W_\gamma$, so actually the partition is one open set, otherwise $U$ wouldn't be connected.

Is this about right, or am I totally wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: Your statement  $p^{-1}(U)=V_\alpha = W_\gamma$ is very wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Given some arbitrary partition into slices  of $p^{-1}(U)=\cup _\alpha V_\alpha$,  the $V_\alpha$ are **exactly** the connected components of $p^{-1}(U)$, which proves the uniqueness of the partition into slices since the connected components of $p^{-1}(U)$ are uniquely determined.
The key point is that $V_\alpha$ is connected (since it is homeomorphic to $U$) whereas any subset $ V_\alpha \subsetneq A \subset p^{-1}(U)$ strictly larger than $V_\alpha$ is guaranteed not to be connected (try to show that trivial fact).

Comment: The last fact that you mention follows from the fact that $V_\alpha$ is homeomorphic to $U$, so if there's some $A$ connected as you write, then it must be homeomorphic to $U$, which is impossible since it's larger than $V_\alpha$; is this right or wrong?

Comment: A priori a subset may be larger than another one and yet be homeomorphic to it:  e.g. $(0,1)\subset \mathbb R$.

Comment: Yes, you are right; forgot about this. Can you give a hint?

Comment: $A=V_\alpha\coprod  (A\setminus V_\alpha)$, both open and closed.